# Install laravel on xampp in arch linux

Tags: laravel-5, archlinux

I have installed xampp in arch linux and also the composer using the command given below:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer |
sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

I have also installed laravel using the following commands.

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

But still, when I type `laravel ne <project>` I get the error

```
bash:laravel is not a command
```

How can I check it is properly installed?

Comment: Simple question, Why don't you use apache instead of xampp ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify you shell script

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

And add  this

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

or this

```
export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```